# Smooth space filling curve over algebraically closed field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, curves, algebraic-curves

Let $X$ be a smooth projective geometrically integral variety of dimension
$m \geq 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$ and a finite subset of points $F \subseteq X$. Then there is a way to construct a smooth projective geometrically integral curve $Y \subseteq X$ s.t. $F \subseteq Y$.
My question is: Does this also work over an algebraically closed field (or more specifically over the complex numbers)? I know the concept of space filling curves as some kind of limit of curves that hit every single point in a higher dimensional space, however these will in general not be smooth. Does the hypothesis that $F$ be a finite set give us anything in this context? Does anoyone know of any research regarding this question?

Comment: There's no such thing as a space-filling curve in algebraic geometry, see for instance [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1828160/algebraic-geometry-look-on-space-filling-curves).

Comment: Well maybe space-filling curve isn't the word I was looking for then. That discussion does not rule out the existence of a curve that intersects a given finite set of points, does it?

Comment: With some reasonable hypotheses you can always find a curve through any finite set of points in a variety. This is generally easier in the infinite field case than in the finite field case.

Comment: @KReiser I think the asker is referring to the language appearing, for example, in corollary 3.5 on page 10 of [Poonen's 2004 paper](https://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/bertini.pdf).

Comment: @Daniel that would have been nice context to have seen in the original post! I was unaware of this term being used in that way, and it's kind of neat. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: That was exactly what i was referring to, sorry for not mentioning it. So is there an explicit way to construct such a curve given a finite set of points or is there some general existence argument to be made?